# Facebook iOS SDK 3.1 how to "Like" an event?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to make an app for iPhone and I'm using [Facebook SDK 3.1](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/) to Like an event, to which I have the ID.

I'm looking through the FB SDK reference and the only way it might make sense is to use [FBRequestConnection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBRequestConnection) to make a POST request to  .../eventID/likes , *if i understand correctly*, but I think I'm missing something. I would have expected, because "Like" is a very popular operation, to be exposed by the SDK in a more easier manner.

Is my understanding correct, regarding the POST request to Graph API to Like an Event ?
Or there is a better solution ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no concept of 'liking' event objects on Facebook. You would need to be liking the feed story about the creation of the event, which you can do via a `POST` to the post_id/likes connection.